# Critical Period for reading, writing, and listening?

Tags: language-acquisition, multilingualism, critical-period

I have heard about about the critical period hypothesis and how that applies to things like accents and stuff, but is there a critical period for reading, writing, and listening? After a certain age or period, can that person never be able to read, write, and listen to a level of a native?

This is a topic of interest because I started learning English when I was about 7. I am fluent and I have pretty much forgotten most of my mother tongue (Korean), however I cannot help but wonder if I started learning English earlier, that I could read faster for example.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Listening happens at the same time (actually usually before) learning to speak. Reading and writing, however, are not activities that humans have genes for; literacy is modern technology, developed only in the last 3000 years, whereas humans have been talking for a million years or so and have coevolved with language use. That's why there's a critical period for oral language. As for writing, it can be pretty simple in a language like Spanish, which just represents the way people actually talk; but it's really really hard in English, which doesn't.

Comment: In the 1990's, there was a reading curriculum called "whole language" which was based on the premise that, with proper stimuli, children can acquire reading and writing more-or-less as they acquire language.   Fortunately for young students, this curriculum has been discredited.   https://www.edweek.org/teaching-learning/kenneth-s-goodman-founding-father-of-whole-language-dead-at-92/2020/05